# End PHP Tag Displaying On My Website

Tags: php, html, css, google-chrome

Well I'm using google chrome if that helps but here's my code.

```
Name:<input style='margin-left:14%;' type='text' readonly='readonly' name='name' value="<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>" />
```

It's a form I'm working on for a comments section and there's a name value set to read only and it displays the username they're logged in as there. But the end PHP tag (?>) is displaying at the bottom of the form and I don't know why. Any bright ideas?

Comment: can show  your full form or link ?

Comment: are you sure the issue happens in this part `<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>` ?

Comment: Can you provide us all the code? I do not believe, the problem is in the part you wrote.

Comment: The PHP code isn't parsed. This meens that you don't have PHP properly setup/configured. Care to share some server setup information?

Answer (score 1):

with the code provided its fine

in your form it may be possible  that you are either not starting the `<?php` or you have closed already only the ?> is not treated same as `<?php`

Answer (score 1):

If you have php tags around your form it will be closed before it gets to the last tag and will show the last tag on the page. 
This

```
<?php <?php ?> ?>
```

the above code will show up as this

?>

Comment: Sorry guys I'm really stupid sometimes. It wasn't in that part I had already ended the PHP tags. Thanks guys.